# Select from table where column in select from another table in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM answers where (id_question in (select id from questions where id_quiz = 3))
```

I need to know how to write it in laravel eloquent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
Answer::whereIn('id_question', function($query) {
    $query->table('questions')->where('id_quiz', 3)
})->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

`table` method is not valid any more, use `from` method instead

```
Answer::whereIn('id_question', function($query) {
    $query->from('questions')->where('id_quiz', 3)
})->get();
```